# Im designing a website mockup in Adobe XD. How can I make this section look more interesting?

Tags: adobe-xd

As the title suggests, how can I make this section look better? The website targets 2 main demographics, "normal" people, and professionals. There will be 2 buttons, one for each main demo. The website is for a health education company, revolving around pregnancy and childbirth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is broad and we can only assume how this would actually work, but you could try:

1. Larger text under the main title. Since this is a headline type area, no reason to have the same font size as in the 2 paragraphs below.
2. Center align the 2 paragraphs below, including titles, text and buttons.
3. To differentiate between the 2 target groups, try an outline around that right block or a light gray background.